# Using DataList control to redirect user on other page and fetch data on that page depending on the button clicked in previous page

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am using a datalist control in which i have a div and some other asp controls.
I have an edit button in it. If I click on edit button, I want to redirect user to another page on which I have some controls and I want information to be filled up in those controls depending upon the button I have clicked in previous page.

Here is the datalist code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">


        <ItemTemplate>
          <div><br /><br /><br />
          <div style="background-color:Silver;height: auto; display:block;" >

                <div id="threadPostLeftDiv" style="width:auto; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; border-color:Black;border-right-color:White;" >
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ImagePreview1" style="margin-right:5px; " ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imageurl") %>' Height="100px" Width="100px" BorderStyle="None" />

                </div>
                <div id="threadPostRightDiv" style=" border-style:solid; border-width:2px;margin-left:-15px; border-color:Black;border-left-color:White;">


                    <asp:Label ID="txtHeadline1"  CssClass="inputprev" style=" font-size:medium; font-weight:bolder;"   Text='<%# Eval("subtitle") %>' Enabled="false"
                        placeholder="Headline" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtDescription1"  CssClass="inputprevdesc1"  Text='<%# Eval("descriptions") %>'
                        Enabled="false" BackColor="Silver" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="Description"  runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="txtOfferHeadline1" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' Enabled="false"  CssClass="inputprev1" 
                         placeholder="Offer Headline" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                     <br />
                </div>

          </div>
                <div style=" float: right;margin-right:10px; ">
                 <button id="btnEdit"  class="css3button1" onserverclick="btnEdit_Click" runat="server">Edit</button>

                </div>

          </div>
</asp:DataList>
```

Please help me in acheiving my goal,give me the code behind file and what events to triggers.
Thank you.

Comment: have you gotten a proper answer or not?

Comment: by the way, you haven't closed <ItemTemplate> in the above provided code. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted html button to link button and fired **onRowCOmmand event** and I got my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well that can be easily achived by doing the following things

1. bind 'btnEdit' commandargument with the id

   ```
   <button id="btnEdit"  class="css3button1" onserverclick="btnEdit_Click" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' >Edit</button>
   ```

in btnEdit_Click event do the following

```
Button bt = (Button)sender;
string recordid = bt.CommandArgument;
Response.Redirect("editrecordno.aspx?recordid="+recordid,true);
```

in editrecordno.aspx page request the querystring  and do the need full.

Comment: I appreciate ur help, but in my code button is an html control and when i tried ur code it is giving an error of invalid type cast.

Comment: you can put runat="server" tag to make it a server control. You can also do onclick="somefunction('<%# Eval("ID") %>');" where somefunction is a javascript code in which you can redirect user to you detailpage.

Comment: replacing html button with server button will make it lot easier.

Comment: you are getting invalid type cast because Button is a asp server control. so please change your html button to asp button and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

in Button_Click event you shoul redirect to another page with `QueryString` paramater
Replace your **edit** `<button>` with this code line

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1"   PostBackUrl='DataEdit.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" Text="Edit" />
```

In DataEdit.aspx put your `FormView` with `DefaultMode=Edit`
Then Add new QueryString Parameter in your `DataSource`

Comment: If you will have any problem, don't hesitate to write